# Regular expression adding something in between patterns, while preserving the patterns in between

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

**In brief**
Given a string like this -

```
MAX_checkTime_Hour('0,1', '=~') and (MAX_checkTime_Day('1,2', '=~') or MAX_checkTime_Day('1,2', '=~')) and MAX_checkGeo_Country('DZ,AO,BJ)
```

I want to insert `<br />` tags before and in between patterns like `and MAX_` or `and (MAX_` or `and ((MAX_` and so on, so that the output is -

```
MAX_checkTime_Hour('0,1', '=~')<br /> and <br />(MAX_checkTime_Day('1,2', '=~') or MAX_checkTime_Day('1,2', '=~'))<br /> and <br />MAX_checkGeo_Country('DZ,AO,BJ)
```

**What I have done so far**
With the following regex replacement I am almost there. The insertion of `<br />` tags is working but I am having to insert a fixed number of `&nbsp;`s -

```
preg_replace("/\s+and\s+MAX_/",'<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;and&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />MAX_',$str);
```

**I wanted to** -

- preserve the exact number of whitespaces.
- preserve the exact number of first brackets before `MAX_`.

So, if the original string was like this -

```
MAX_checkTime_Hour('0,1', '=~') <3 white spaces here> and <5 white spaces here> #2 first brackets here#MAX_checkTime_Day('1,2', '=~')
```

I would like the output to be -

```
MAX_checkTime_Hour('0,1', '=~')<br /> <3 white spaces here> and <5 white spaces here> <br /><first brackets here>MAX_checkTime_Day('1,2', '=~')
```

**Update**
I tried with the following assuming that the variable number of whitespaces would be stored in variables, but it did not work -

```
preg_replace("/{\s+}and{\s+}MAX_/",'<br />$1and$2<br />MAX_',$str);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you forgot about 'or' operator in the source (located right before third MAX_). There is alt. version of regexp - it's more generic (because it can match and safely replace both 'and' & 'or' operators) and it has been little more optimized (because it doesn't use look-ahead/look-behind syntax):

```
$result = preg_replace('/(\s+(and|or)\s+)(\(*MAX_)/', '<br/>$1<br/>$2', $str);
```

Also it [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) compatible, replacement string doesn't contains any parts of the source string

Comment: Thanks, this works and is very clear. I was indeed very close !

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
$result = preg_replace('/(?<=and)(?=[\s(]+MAX_)/im', '<br />and<br />MAX_\'', $subject);
```

**RegEx explanation**

```
<!--
(?<=and)(?=[\s\(]+MAX_)

Options: case insensitive; ^ and $ match at line breaks

Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind) «(?<=and)»
   Match the characters “and” literally «and»
Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=[\s\(]+MAX_)»
   Match a single character present in the list below «[\s\(]+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
      A whitespace character (spaces, tabs, and line breaks) «\s»
      A ( character «\(»
   Match the characters “MAX_” literally «MAX_»
-->
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this does not preserve the whitespace. Please note that in the output, I want the whitespace between `<br />` and `and` and that between `and` and the second `<br />` to be the same as there was before replacement.

Comment: Then try this: ``$result = preg_replace('/(?<=and)( +)(?=\(+MAX_)/im', '<br />$1and<br />$1MAX_\'', $subject);``

Comment: yes this works. a +1 for you but Rusted's answers looks more clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$str = "MAX_checkTime_Hour('0,1', '=~') and (MAX_checkTime_Day('1,2', '=~') or MAX_checkTime_Day('1,2', '=~')) and MAX_checkGeo_Country('DZ,AO,BJ)";

echo preg_replace("/(\s+)and(\s+)(\(*MAX_)/", "<br />$1and$2<br />$3", $str);
```

**output:**

```
MAX_checkTime_Hour('0,1', '=~')<br /> and <br />(MAX_checkTime_Day('1,2', '=~') or MAX_checkTime_Day('1,2', '=~'))<br /> and <br />MAX_checkGeo_Country('DZ,AO,BJ)
```